Azure pipeline failing with error MSB4018: The "LocateBuildToolsConfigTask" task failed unexpectedly
Azure devops pipeline maui build is failing
Using Mobile.BuildTools (2.0.245) - it fails while building unit tests with the error

[error]C:\Users\VssAdministrator.nuget\packages\mobile.buildtools\2.0.245\build\Mobile.BuildTools.targets(37,5): Error MSB4018: The "LocateBuildToolsConfigTask" task failed unexpectedly.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Security.Permissions, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'System.Security.Permissions, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'

Using Mobile.BuildTools versions 2.0.109-pre, 2.0.153-pre - Unit tests are building successfully but it is failing while building the project with the same error

[error]C:\Users\VssAdministrator.nuget\packages\mobile.buildtools\2.0.109-pre\build\Mobile.BuildTools.targets(37,5): Error MSB4018: The "LocateBuildToolsConfigTask" task failed unexpectedly.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Security.Permissions, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. The system cannot find the file specified.

It is working with .net7 and the errors are when I try to build using .net8
vmImage used is windows-2022
Expecting it to build successfully

Is the build successful in local using .NET8? You said: It is working with .net7 and the errors are when I try to build using .net8. When you upgraded from .NET 7 to 8, did you modify your project to adapt to .NET 8? If not, please refer to this Upgrading .NET MAUI from .NET 7 to .NET 8 first.    If possible, can you please create and share a Minimal, Reproducible code example and the YAML you are using to better troubleshooting the issue?

Yes, developer has made the necessary modifications to adapt to .net8 and was able to build successfully in local.

Hi, maybe you can try the customized Nuget package I mentioned in the answer to workaround the issue.

I found this same error issue [.NET 8.0] Build crash System.Security.Permissions missing  in the Mobile.BuildTools issue list.

Error MSB4018: The "LocateBuildToolsConfigTask" task failed unexpectedly. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Security.Permissions

It is a known issue and hasn't been fixed.  In the issue, the Author shared the customized Nuget package using the System.Text.Json instead of Newtonsoft.Json to work around the issue.
